# How to extract templates from Silverlight Toolkit themes

Tags: xaml, user-interface, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

There are a few themes made available for free in Silverlight apps.

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203&referringTitle=Home

but they come as dlls. Is there a way to extract actual templates in XAML in order to edit them?

Comment: You can't just right-click -> Edit Template? I'm not sure, I always just [made my own](http://professionalsweb.net/GleemTheme/GleemTheme-v.05/PrecompiledWeb/TwoToneControlTheme-CWSite/) if you want one, that one doesn't have an NDA on it.

Comment: Try include the dll and edit template with Blend

Comment: I don't think so, as the toolkit comes with a special template system that isn't the normal way of styling in Silverlight. There are, however, four in my opinion better themes that came out a little later. Just google for "four silverlight themes" and you'll find them. Those come in the normal fashion of xaml resource files and I've used modified versions of them extensively. They look really decent.

Comment: thanks. do you mean - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14590 ?